# Table using Latex in overleaf shows at the bottom of the table

Tags: latex, overleaf

Despite specifiyin that the table should show where it is place in the code `\begin{table}[ht]` it shows at the bottom of the document. I am using Latex in overleaf.

Here is what I try:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Example of profit developments}
    \label{tab:table3}
    \begin{tabular}{llrrrrr}
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Case 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Case 2} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Constant\\ mark-up assumption\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Increasing\\ mark-up assumption\end{tabular}}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    & {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}National\\Accounts Indicators\end{tabular}} & {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Initial Period\\ T0\end{tabular}} & T1 & {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\%Change from\\ T0 to T1\end{tabular}} & T1 & {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\%Change from\\ T0 to T1\end{tabular}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (1) & Mark-up &20\%&20\% &0\% &15\% &-25\% \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (2) & Real units & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (3) & Intermediate costs & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (4) & Labour costs & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (5) & Total costs = (3) + (4) & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (6) & Profits & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (7) & Nominal gross output = (5) + (6) & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (8) & Unit profits = (6) / (2) & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (9) & Price = (7) / (2) & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
    (10) & Profit share = (6) / [(6) + (4)] & & & & & \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
      \\Source: US Bureau of Economic Analysis
      \end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre]. Without seeing your document, I'd guess there is not enough room for the table.

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/707251/36296